# Pending Update will fail in High Sierra

Tags: mac-appstore, software-update, high-sierra

I have just updated my os to High Sierra after a format. Through the App Store app, a version update was required (namely macOS High Sierra 10.13 Supplemental Update) so I did it.

Then as it was installing I encountered the following error,

`The path /System/Installation/Packages/OSInstall.mpkg appears to be missing or damaged`

I tried to fix it using some details from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299808/high-sierra-the-path-system-installation-packages-osinstall-mpkg-appears-to-b). However the `find` command couldn't locate the missing file. For the record I entered all the commands in the aforementioned post.

So I went trying some stuff (which I don't quite remember) and somehow I managed to boot my computer normally (boots in the update resulted in a continuous update loop that I managed to exit). And now I have the same update pending in my App Store and of course I want to execute it.

Now, I wouldn't want to fall back to the bad update situation so I was thinking maybe to download the update again.

How can I delete the files from the bad update?

Is this strategy going to make any difference?

(running on a MacBook Pro 15-inch 2016)

Comment: Try reinstalling High Sierra. Boot into recovery mode (Command + R) and reinstall without deleting your drive. After that done, restart, boot again into recovery mode and repair your disk permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading the [update from Apple's website](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1937?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) rather than through the App Store, and installing from that package.

Comment: Did the trick, and the update requirement in the App Store update tab has now vanished! Thanks!