# The path /System/Installation/Packages/OSInstall.mpkg appears to be missing or damaged - OSX 10.13.1 - High Sierra

Tags: macos, high-sierra

This is not a duplicate of this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299808/high-sierra-the-path-system-installation-packages-osinstall-mpkg-appears-to-b). The situation is a bit different. In my case, I have already installed High Sierra on a MacBook Pro 15inch 2017. I encountered this issue when updating the Security Update 2017-001. It got stuck in a boot loop where upon entering my password, it would send me to install High Sierra. (I've installed it over a month ago). Then it would show this error.

Comment: Might be related to SIP, perhaps try booting into safe mode (hold shift on boot) and see if you can update there?

Comment: Please do not post the answer as part of the question, use the answer section below instead

Comment: Personal experience:
Brickbats to Apple for wasting 2-3 hours of my time last night with a <12 months old iMac 27" (upgraded spec). Same error, not starting up etc.. Apple, I really do expect to get what I pay for i.e I pay more for Apple computers than any others, so I expect better from you. Steve Jobs would not have tolerated this nonsense. Heads should roll over this stuff up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution which has not been mentioned in the locked thread, is to hold the `option` key upon startup to use the Startup Manager to select out of the OSInstall route. Hope this helps anyone else running into this issue, as I've spend too many hours trying to fix this.

Comment: That is a nice workaround. I do not trust my system anymore, but at least now I can do a solid backup of my files. Thanks :)

Comment: Holding shift work in my case!

Comment: Did anyone find a permament solution? I have to google this answer each time my MBA restarts.

Comment: This is a permanent solution. Booting up this way bypassed the install route and sent me on my way to the login page. The install route hasn't show up after. Tho if you're getting to the install page, it could be that it's trying to install a new version. So you can just remove the update files after you've logged in.

Comment: thank for this! Save my butt. I can't believe apple has such stupic install software. If it knows the install can't work, why does it keep looping when you restart. Most users are going to feel stuck. WTF Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Answer on our end has been to boot into Safe Mode and install the OSX 10.13.3 combo update (Installs ALL 10.13.3 files, not just upgrades from 10.13.2 to 10.13.3) from here:
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1953?locale=en_US

The app store version is not the combo update and it appears the push from 10.13.2 to 10.13.3 is the cause of this error. This will overwrite whatever Apple did on the backend to screw up the individual 10.13.3 update.