# Mac os Upgrade 10.13.4 Cannot Find Installer Resources

Tags: macos

when I try to upgrade my MacBook Pro to 10.13.4,it reported that it cannot find Installer resources. Anyone has solution to solve it? [image]

Answer (score 3):

Click Anywhere, then Apple -> Select Startup Disk -> Restart.

This is the same as this question.
[High Sierra - The path /System/Installation/Packages/OSInstall.mpkg appears to be missing or damaged](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299808/high-sierra-the-path-system-installation-packages-osinstall-mpkg-appears-to-b/313857#313857)