# Installed High Sierra but Macbook still boots MacOS Installer volume and fails

Tags: install, high-sierra

I recently installed MacOS High Sierra on my MacBook Pro, but now every time I restart my Computer it boots the MacOS Installer volume but fails to complete, because `System/Installation/Packages/OSInstall.mpkg appears to be missing or damaged`

Now, I've read [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299808/high-sierra-the-path-system-installation-packages-osinstall-mpkg-appears-to-b) (here the installation failed with the same error message), that you can just select the regular HD to mount, which works, and install the update, but there's no update to be installed, as the installation actually was successful.
My computer works fine if I boot it with the HD.
Any ideas on why it still wants to boot on the Installer?

Specs:

- MacBook Pro 13" 2014
- MacOS High Sierra 10.13.3

**note**

In the link I provided, one of the answers suggested finding and moving the `OSInstall.mpkg` file, but I can't find it at all.

Comment: what happens if you select (or-re-select) the correct boot drive in the Startup Disk preference pane?

Comment: Now it's booting MacintoshHD again by default. Thank you.
Is it necessary/possible to remove the Installer?

Comment: I have not seen that issue before, so I am not sure if just the startup disk was not set right or that something needs to be fixed (or both...)